# App transport policy on a command line tool in mac application

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, shell, cocoa-touch

I am building a cocoa touch framework which has a **mac app** (command line tool/shell app) inside so I can call it and execute stuff when building my iOS app from build phases.

The problem is that the command line target I have added to the iOS project didn't have any `Info.plist` file so I created one but the transport policy settings doesn't have any effect on it.

Below is a screenshot of my iOS app build log, trying to execute my console app:
[image]

Comment: try my code its help you for solve your issue

Comment: You need to show your Mac App's Info.plist.  It sounds like you added one and tried to put in the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, but it isn't working.  We'll need to see your Map App's setup to provide help.

Comment: Command Line Tools do NOT have an `Info.plist`, answers suggesting to edit the `Info.plist` file will not work.

Comment: you create a mac app not iPhone device app . its my miss understanding .

Comment: Did you ever get it to work ? I also need to set the app transport security on a command line application.....

Answer (score 0):

Try Just Once to configure this dictionary into Appdelegate File.
This is basic structure of `NSAppTransportSecurity`.

```
NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary {

    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads : Boolean

    NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia : Boolean

    NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent : Boolean

    NSAllowsLocalNetworking : Boolean

    NSExceptionDomains : Dictionary {

        <domain-name-string> : Dictionary {

            NSIncludesSubdomains : Boolean

            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads : Boolean

            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion : String

            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy : Boolean   // Default value is YES

            NSRequiresCertificateTransparency : Boolean

        }

    }

}
```

I dont know It it works but lets make a try to this.
You can Refer to this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) for it.
Hope this thing works

Answer (score -2):

To improve the `security` of connections between an app and web services, connections must follow best practices (your web service request should: 1) use `HTTPS` and 2) be encrypted using `TLS v1.2` with forward secrecy.). Please check the [App Transport Security Technote.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)

As posted on your screenshot (`LIVEUI` custom shell script), you are working with non-secure web services, so you have to bypass the App Transport Security behaviour. Follow the below steps:-

- Open your app in Xcode.
- Find the `Info.plist` file in Project Navigator and "right-mouse" click on it and choose the `Open As > Source Code` menu option.
- Put the following properties block inside of the main properties dictionary (under the first `<dict>`).

---

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>        
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads A Boolean value used to disable App Transport
>   Security for any domains not listed in the NSExceptionDomains
>   dictionary. Listed domains use the settings specified for that domain.
>
> The default value of NO requires the default App Transport Security
>   behaviour for all connections.

Comment: well, as mentioned @mttrb, "Command Line Tools do NOT have an Info.plist, answers suggesting to edit the Info.plist file will not work." :(